# Sections in local & LIVE out of sync

Tags: projectconfig, project.yaml

I created a new section (single) on my  local environment.

Then I pushed it to LIVE. There it is not showing up in the entries CP.

But it is showing up in the settings.

So I guess the project.yaml hasn't been applied correctely or something.

If I excecute `./craft project-config/rebuild` on LIVE I get the error:

> Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The
>   directory does not exist:
>   /path/assets'
>
> in
>   /path/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php:213

But this has nothing to do with assets

Also. If I go to said section in the settings and try to save it there is the following error:

> 2019-07-15 14:06:43
>   [-][1][aaa64a91c1fffdd268c2d774dc31daa4][error][yii\base\Exception]
>   yii\base\Exception: Couldn’t save single entry due to validation
>   errors on the slug and/or URI in
>   /path/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Sections.php:1561

What now?

Answer (score 2):

If I create a folder `assets` at that location it works. I don't know what this asset folder is about.